Mount azure files share on linux with Entra-ID user rights
My company uses Azure Files and Entra ID in combination with Entra Domain Services.
Windows users add their Entra-Account to their Win11-PC and can then mount the companys fileshares as their respective users.
I have a linux machine, is there a way to mount our fileshares as my entra user?
The fileshare uses kerberos authentication, in case that makes a difference.
The domain is domain.local, which if I am reading the documentation right might be problem due to it not being routable.
